# email sending in jsp

Tags: jsp, sendmail

I developed a web jsp/servlet application to send mail to users in my database table, keeping in mind that the users will be many, how can i send the multiple messages to all of them(in the background) without one (admin) having to wait to see the email servlet finish its execution? 
i can send email using the java class and smtp.gmail.com, while iterating the emails and the message, but i would like it to be in the background after one presses the send button to all users. please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Mail API for this.

1. User clicks send button in JSP page.
2. Request will be forwarded to Servlet
3. Servlet fetches all the email-IDs from Database
4. Then, Servlet calls a Utility class that sends the email by setting given the TO address in the message.

Below link might be helpful for you.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-sending-email.htm

Please let me know if you are looking for any further information.